# How do I use the contents of an array as a variable name?

Tags: autohotkey

Currently I store the contents of an array into a variable, then set that variable up using two % and store a value.  My current code looks like this:

```
Test := {asdf: "blah"}
Temp := Test["asdf"]
%Temp% := "boo"
; above line is be the same as blah := "boo", but blah came from a variable
msgbox %blah% ; outputs "boo"
```

I don't like having to use the `Temp` variable like this.

The following compiles but `blah` stays blank:

```
(Test["asdf"]) := "boo"
%Test%["asdf"] := "boo"
```

The following gives me a compile error:

```
%(Test["asdf"])% := "boo"
```

I have a vague idea that it should be possible but I just can't find the syntax for it.  How do I directly use the array instead of having to put it in a temp variable?

Comment: The reason is the program is dynamically driven, and I have controlled systems in place to setup the variables.  This is not a one-off-thing that I'm screwing around with.  I have a GIANT list of data like this, and this list can change.  Instead of hunting in the program to update the list of variables, I'm creating them dynamically, and having other files control the output.

Comment: There are also some very interesting usages by using data as a variable.  If you have a list of items and you are looking for duplicates as you populate an array, you can do an array[key] call to detect whether it has been previously assigned instead of looping through your existing data.  You just changed an O(n) search into an O(1) search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out.

The problem here is creating variables using dynamic data may cause invalid variable names to be created.  All sorts of ways to screw up here (spaces, UTF-8 code, etc).

One safer way is to use Associative Arrays:

```
Output := Object()
Test := {asdf: "blah"}
Output[(Test["asdf"])] := "boo"
msgbox % Output["blah"]
```

There are [less restrictions on keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Keys) than variable names.

Comment: But ... your `Test` already is an associative array. That's how you can key it with the name "asdf". (This is better than dynamically creating global variables).

Comment: Test isn't dynamically created.  In actual usage, Test's data would come from a file, which basically has data -> name pairs.  The Output will be for putting the data together so it will be processed by a loop later.

Answer (score 0):

```
globalWrapper(NameOfTheGlobalVar, LocalVar) {
    global
    %NameOfTheGlobalVar% := LocalVar
}


Test := {asdf: "blah"}
globalWrapper(Test["asdf"], "boo")

msgbox %blah% ; outputs "boo"
```